# Best way to sort through components Vue JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a site where I would like to add a search function using Vue 2, the search will be applied to the components which are generated on page load via a JSON file.

The key words I want to use for this are included in the JSON file that is fetched. (Name and tag) (The components are called pools by the way) 
 I was thinking to use a computed property however i am a little bit confused on how I would go about doing that

This is what i have so far for my search bar component but im confused one how the computed property should be.

```
<template>
    <div class="search">
        <input type="text" v-model="search" placeholder="Search for pools">
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        mounted() {
            console.log('Search Box Mounted')
        },
        data(){
            return{
                search:''
            }
        },
        computed: {
            filteredPools: function(){

            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

This code is responsible for showing the pool list

```
<template>
    <div class="container pool" v-bind:id="'poolalgo-' + algo">
        <h2 class="type text-center">{{algo}}</h2>
        <hr class="poolruler" />
        <div class="row">
            <pool v-for="pool in pools" :pool="pool" :key="pool.tag">
            </pool>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        mounted() {
            console.log('PoolList mounted.')
        },
        props:['pools','algo']
    }
</script>
```

Then there is just the component that shows the actual pool

```
<template>

    <div class="col-xl-3 centered icon">
        <a v-bind:href="pool.url" target="_blank">
            <img class="logo img rounded-circle" v-bind:src="pool.image" height="120px" width="120px">
        </a>
        <h4>{{pool.name}}</h4>
        <p>Symbol/Tag: {{pool.tag}}</p>
        <p>Block Time: {{pool.blocktime}}</p>
        //ect
        <br>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: ['pool'],

        mounted() {
            console.log('Pool mounted.')
        },
    }
</script>
```

In my main page this is what calls the pool list

```
<pool-list v-for="(pools,algo) in poolConfig" :pools="pools" :algo="algo"></pool-list>
```

Comment: You want to sort the `pool` array by a property name? And show the result in that order?

Comment: yes i believe that is what i want to do but im confused on how @Frondor Edit: By the Name and Tag that is part of each pool object in the json file

Comment: @ThatPurpleGuy, what do you need? sort or filter? if filter, which keywords?

Comment: @Sphinx I need a filter I believe i only want to show the pool components that are related to the value in the search box based off of the data in the pool object specifically Tag and Name

Comment: If the test input is not in the same component as the list, you'll need a shared state, like Vuex. Or use the `$root` instance if the app is small enough.

Comment: @Frondor its a one page application how would i do the $root instance

Comment: I'll create an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run this snippet (full page) and check if that's what you want. It's a single component, but you can follow the comments so you can use it like you want (the search input component + the list component)

#### Search component

```
<template>
  <div class="search">
      <input type="text" @input="emitSearch" placeholder="Search for pools">
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    methods: {
    emitSearch (ev) {
      this.$root.$emit('app:search', ev.target.value)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

#### List component

```
<template>
 <div class="col-xl-3 centered icon" v-for="pool in list" :key="pool.name">
    <a v-bind:href="pool.image" target="_blank">
        <img class="logo img rounded-circle" v-bind:src="pool.image" height="120px" width="120px">
    </a>
    <h4>{{pool.name}}</h4>
    <p>Symbol/Tag: {{pool.tag}}</p>
    <p>Block Time: {{pool.blocktime}}</p>
    //ect
    <br>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      search: '',
      orderBy: 'name', // sort by property
      pools: [ // raw list
        {name: 'Yellow pool', tag: 'yellow', blocktime: 123, image: 'https://placehold.it/120'},
        {name: 'Blue pool', tag: 'blue', blocktime: 123, image: 'https://placehold.it/120'},
        {name: 'Purple pool', tag: 'purple', blocktime: 123, image: 'https://placehold.it/120'},
        {name: 'Black pool', tag: 'black', blocktime: 123, image: 'https://placehold.it/120'},
      ]
    }
  },
  computed: {
    list () {
      return this.pools.filter(p => { // first using this.search
        return p.name.toLowerCase()
          .indexOf(this.search.toLowerCase()) > -1
      })
        .sort((a, b) => { // sort using this.orderBy
          const first = a[this.orderBy].toLowerCase()
          const next = b[this.orderBy].toLowerCase()
          if (first > next) {
            return 1
          }
          if (first < next) {
            return -1
          }
          return 0
        })
    }
  },
  created () {
    this.$root.$on('app:search', search => {
      this.search = search
    })
  },
  beforeDestroy () {
    // dont forget to remove the listener
    this.$root.$off('app:search')

  }
}
</script>
```

## Working fiddle

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data () {
    return {
      search: '',
      orderBy: 'name', // sort by property
      pools: [ // raw list
        {name: 'Yellow pool', tag: 'yellow', blocktime: 123, image: 'https://placehold.it/120'},
        {name: 'Blue pool', tag: 'blue', blocktime: 123, image: 'https://placehold.it/120'},
        {name: 'Purple pool', tag: 'purple', blocktime: 123, image: 'https://placehold.it/120'},
        {name: 'Black pool', tag: 'black', blocktime: 123, image: 'https://placehold.it/120'},
      ]
    }
  },
  computed: { // list component computed props
    list () {
      return this.pools.filter(p => { // first using this.search
        return p.name.toLowerCase()
          .indexOf(this.search.toLowerCase()) > -1
      })
        .sort((a, b) => { // sort using this.orderBy
          const first = a[this.orderBy].toLowerCase()
          const next = b[this.orderBy].toLowerCase()
          if (first > next) {
            return 1
          }
          if (first < next) {
            return -1
          }
          return 0
        })
    }
  },
  methods: { // search component method
    emitSearch (ev) {
      this.$root.$emit('app:search', ev.target.value)
    }
  },
  created () { // list component lifecycle hook
    this.$root.$on('app:search', search => {
      this.search = search
    })
  },
  beforeDestroy () { // list component lifecycle hook
    // dont forget to remove the listener
    this.$root.$off('app:search')

  }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script>Vue.config.productionTip = false</script>

<div id="app">
  <!-- search component emits 'app:search' event -->
  <div class="search">
    <input type="text" @input="emitSearch" placeholder="Search for pools">
  </div>
  <hr>
  <!-- list component listens 'app:search' event -->
  <div class="col-xl-3 centered icon" v-for="pool in list" :key="pool.name">
    <a v-bind:href="pool.image" target="_blank">
        <img class="logo img rounded-circle" v-bind:src="pool.image" height="120px" width="120px">
    </a>
    <h4>{{pool.name}}</h4>
    <p>Symbol/Tag: {{pool.tag}}</p>
    <p>Block Time: {{pool.blocktime}}</p>
    //ect
    <br>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: exactly what i want. I will award correct answer when i implement it properly

Comment: Just added the code for the splitted version. Have fun

Comment: getting this " Property or method "search" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property." error for the search component

Comment: Just remove it from the input, that was my mistake, leave only `@input="emitSearch"`, look the last edition I made

Comment: Bit confused on the list component where the return is i have just a prop right now and no `data()` returning @Frondor

Comment: The property in the `data` object was just an example, you're supposed to pass an object _LIKE_ the one I wrote as an example, in that prop.
`<pool-list :pools="pools"></pool-list>` (`pools` is the data array)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170119/discussion-between-thatpurpleguy-and-frondor).

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like filter pools using this.search, follow below steps:

1. Add one prop for your `pools` component to accept **filter-text** from parent component.
2. Create one computed for your `pools` component, then in the computed method, use [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to apply your custom filter.
3. change `<pool v-for="pool in pools"> to``

```html
<template>
    <div class="container pool" v-bind:id="'poolalgo-' + algo">
        <h2 class="type text-center">{{algo}}</h2>
        <hr class="poolruler" />
        <div class="row">
            <pool v-for="pool in filteredPools" :pool="pool" :key="pool.tag">
            </pool>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        mounted() {
            console.log('PoolList mounted.')
        },
        props:['pools','algo', 'filterText'],
        computed: {
            filteredPools: function(){ //filter out tag|name includes this.search
              return this.pools.filter((item)=>{
                return this.filterText in item.tag or this.filterText in item.name
              })
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Finally, in your parent component, use `<pools v-bind:filter-text="search">`

Comment: the Pools component cant be inside of the search component. And pools has to be brought in using a prop

Comment: @ThatPurpleGuy, updated anwer, now it will accept one prop from parent component to apply filter.

Comment: I updated the post im confused what im puting in the search tag on the main page. `Property or method "filteredPools" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render.` and `Property or method "pools" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property.` and `The data property "pools" is already declared as a prop. Use prop default value instead.` are my errors